# Expanding Character Limit

Tags: php

Has anyone experienced making a compose form for a blog?

I have this problem that works perfectly fine in my localhost but when I try to upload in on the server things are not working out.

My problem is, when I am running at localhost it accepts unlimited number of character and save to database as "text" data type but running it on the site it only accepts 10,000 character, beyond that it return an error. What could be the problem here?

Here's my code.

```
<form action="savepost.php" method="POST">
<fieldset style="width:600px; height:580px">
<br><strong>Title</strong> <input id="posttitle" name="posttitle" type="text">
<br><br><strong>Content</strong>
<br><textarea id="postform" name="postform" style="width:600px; height:450px; resize: none"></textarea>
<br><input type="submit" value="Post" id="postbutton"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

savepost.php is basically a mysql insert process.

Comment: sir, have updated my question together with the code requested.

Comment: Assuming you are using MySQL try storing the data as `longtext`.

Comment: Are the MySQL tables same on local and hosting server ?

Comment: I have mysql tables both on my localhost and server.

Answer (score 1):

try check/set in php.ini or in .htaccess

```
post_max_size=20M
```

Comment: do i have to put post_max_size=20M in .htaccess?

Comment: if you want to set it to entire server then in php.ini, if you want to set it just for one project then to .htaccess http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure that the Datatype in your Database Schema Table is set to `TEXT`, `LONGTEXT` or `MEDIUMTEXT`in both local and hosting server.

```
TEXT : 65,000 characters
MEDIUMTEXT: 16 million characters
LONGTEXT : 4 trillion
```

2- In your **php.ini** set `post_max_size` to your desired numbers of million characters. Default is (in WAMP) `post_max_size = 8M`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your MySQL database schema to allow more text than 10,000 characters.

According to this document ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html ) you should use the `LONGTEXT` type, which has a limit of 4 gibibytes of text, certainly enough space :)

Comment: @Dai I already used TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT but there is no luck. I am wondering if it has to do with the post_max_size. Here is what the w3schools stated. 

Note: However, there is an 8 Mb max size for the POST method, by default (can be changed by setting the post_max_size in the php.ini file).